# SQL command to prompt a pop up box to have a user input a username to add the value to the alter user "username" command

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to write a script that can be ran to unlock a user from an oracle database. I can connect to the sqlserver, and run the command manually, but id like to have an input box pop up, ask for the username, and input that value into the alter user username account unlock; command.

Comment: Info not usable

Comment: It has already been answered.

Comment: Came to me as review task, I did some cleanup. It doesn't matter if answered or not;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substitution variable (`&variable_name`)

```
SQL> ALTER USER &user_name ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
Enter value for user_name: hr

old:ALTER USER &user_name ACCOUNT UNLOCK
new:ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK

User HR altered.
```

Comment: dude you are a lifesaver

Comment: one more thing, what if I wanted the window to close after the user has been altered?